# Firefox 89.0 on Ubuntu - poor performance

Tags: 20.04, firefox, performance

I've clean install of **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**, and **Firefox 89.0**.

Performance of Firefox is very poor, you can see that even when scrolling simple pages, it looks like there are just **10 FPS**.

I know that FF does not support hardware acceleration for my config but I think that my specs should still allow it to work fluent.

Any recommendation what should I do to improve FF performance?

My Hardware specs:

- AMD® Ryzen 7 5800x 8-core processor × 16
- NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070 Ti]
- RAM 31.3 GiB

Comment: Is it also slow if you use Chrome? What version Nvidia driver?

Comment: Nvidia drivers -> 460.80, Chrome runs fluent.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to install Firefox ESR from the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=bionic):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr
```

and then launch it using `firefox-esr` command to test.

Comment: Does it really run better? Or just a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try this newer Nvidia driver, version 465.31, which can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]

Comment: I've used both 460 and 465 with no success.

Comment: @JacekStyrylski Boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.04 USB/DVD and see if Firefox works there. Report back.

Comment: @JacekStyrylski Log into a different user account and see if FF works there.

Comment: @henioStraszny Status please...

Comment: @henioStraszny Status please...